# Regex - Match length based on value inside match (using variables ?)

Tags: regex, string, variables, expression

I'd like to know if its possible to use a value inside the expression as a variable for a second part of the expression

The goal is to extract some specific strings from a memory dump. One part of the string is based on a (more or less) fixed structure that can be described well using regular expressions. The Problem is the second part of the string that has a variable length and no "footer" or anything that can be "matched" as an "END". 
Instead there is a length indicator on position 2 of the first part.

Here is a simplified example string that id like to find (an all others) inside a large file

00 **24** AA BB AA DD EE FF GG HH II JJ **########### ( # beeing unwanted data)**

Lets assume that the main structure would allways be 00 XX AA BB AA - but the last part (starting from DD) will be variable in length for each string based on the value of XX

I know that this can be done in code outside regex but iam curious if its possible :)

Comment: `awk` (or `python`, or even `perl`) might be a better option here than trying to do it within the limitations of regexes...

Comment: Thanks. It is asked out of curiosity. Iam fairly new to regular expressions and thought it might be somewhere down the road...For now iam using python and multiple search strings for this. For each "first part" it builds a new one with the found length indicator.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** NO

**Long answer:**

You can acheive what you want in two steps:

- Extract the value inside string
- Build dynamically a regexp for matching

*PSEUDO CODE*

```
s:='00 24 AA BB AA DD EE FF GG HH II JJ ###########'
re:=/00 (\d{2}) AA BB AA/

if 
   s::matches(re)
then
   match := re::match(s)
   len := matches(1)

   dynamicRE := new Regexp(re::toString() + ' (?:[A-Z]{2} ){' + len + '}') 
   // dynamicRE == /00 (\d{2}) AA BB AA (?:[A-Z]{2} ){24,24}/

   if s::matches(dynamicRE) then
      // MATCH !!
   else
      // NO MATCH !!
   end if
end if
```

Comment: I was afraid that this would be the only option, since this is basically what i was doing before. So there is no way of defining variables with (and inside) a regular expression ? Anyway, thank you for pointing that out :-)